# What Centos package contains the libraries for -lSM -lICE linker options?

Tags: centos, rhel, compiling, linker

Apologies if this has already been answered; I am having trouble finding an existing post (either on SE or linux forums) which solves the issue.

I need to install the package(s) that enables the -lSM and -lICE linker options for compiling some C/C++ code that uses plotting libraries (see here for an example: [C Compiling and Linking](https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/en/html_node/C-Compiling-and-Linking.html)).

Here's a snippet of the error messages I'm getting:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSM
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lICE
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am quite certain that the issue is the package simply not being installed. What is the name of the package? I am running on CentOS7/Redhat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for libSM.so and libICE.so, provided by the libSM-devel and libICE-devel packages.

Basically, if you are linking with -l`<something>`, look in `/usr/lib64/lib<something>.so`. An even faster result is to skip the step of finding the package name and run:

```
 yum install  /usr/lib64/lib<something>.so
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there some methodology to finding what package a particular option is contained in? For some, I can now see that it's relatively straightforward (e.g., "l" -> "library" so lSM -> libSM), but for others I don't see a pattern (e.g., libXm is in motif). Should I just use the "whatprovides" option to figure them out?

Comment: As I said in the answer, you can skip the ‘yum what provided ...’ and just directly use ‘yum install /path/to/library’. And the -l in the link command is to link against a library, so it’s not ‘lSM’ but ‘-l’ + ‘SM’.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification; I didn't realize that the '-l' prefix was to link against a library. But in that case, I don't see how I could figure out what package something lives in. For example, how would I know that "libXm" is in "motif" rather than "libX11"?

Comment: ‘yum provides /path/to/file’ will tell you. There’s no better place than to look in the RPM db.